# Pygame convert surface into sprite

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, pygame-surface

I want to make a game with cards, something like Heartstone, but a lot simplier (coz I am not pro programmer). This is just part of program

```
import pygame 
class Card:
def AdCard(self, AdCard):
    self.AdCard = AdCard
def HpCard(self, HpCard):
    self.HpCard = HpCard
def Picture(self, Picture):
    self.Picture = Picture
def Special(self, Special):
    if Special == "Heal":
        pass

pygame.init()
display = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)


swordsman = Card()
swordsman_picture = pygame.image.load("Swordsman.png").convert()
swordsman.Picture(swordsman_picture)
print(type(swordsman.Picture))
```

Now the problem is that it prints that type of Picture is class 'pygame.Surface' but I want for this picture to be sprite.
How to do that.
Tnx.

Comment: `Sprite` is a class which use `Surface` to keep image and `Rect` to keep positon and size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Sprite` is a class which use `Surface` to keep image and `Rect` to keep positon and size.

```
class Card(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, surface):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = surface

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect() # size and position

# and then

one_card = Card(swordsman_picture)
```

(see Pygame documentation: [pygame.sprite.Sprite](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) )

or probably but I did't see this before

```
one_card = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
one_card.image = swordsman_picture
one_card.rect = one_card.image.get_rect() # size and position
```

---

**BTW**: Use "CamelCase" names only for classes names - to make code more readable - even StackOveflor editor treads `Picture`, `AdCard`, etc as class name and use blue color. For functions and variables use `lower_case` names.

---

This seems useless

```
def Picture(self, Picture):
    self.Picture = Picture

swordsman.Picture(swordsman_picture)
```

you can do the same in one line - and make it more readable.

```
swordsman.Picture = swordsman_picture
```